# Is there any point to using <section>, etc?

Tags: html

One of the most hyped aspects of HTML5 (or more accurately the new HTML specification) were the additions of `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, etc. The goal was to introduce a new outlining algorithm. For example, the following document:

```
<h1>Types of dogs</h1>
<section>
 <h1>Doberman</h1>
 <aside>
  <h1>Advertisement</h1>
 </aside>
</section>
```

should produce this outline:

```
1. Types of dogs
   1. Doberman
      1. Advertisement
```

Theoretically, `<aside>` shouldn't be part of the main outline, but [gsnedder's tool](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) includes it anyway. Furthermore, it's widely known that no implementation of this algorithm in user agents exist<sup>1</sup>. This discourages me from adopting the tags. While they would be "best practice" because they add more "semantic" meaning than `<div>`, the way a document would be structured (to preserve the actual intended outline) using these tags would defeat the purpose. The same effect can be achieved by careful usage of header tags, structuring of information in the source code itself, and CSS.

Is there a strong reason to use these tags?

<sup>1</sup>: Source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) and www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html (although W3 likes to editorialize WHATWG specs it's still semi-authoritative)

Comment: Have you thought about people that use screen readers? Google indexing your pages being able to make more sense of the content?

Comment: "Theoretically, <aside> shouldn't be part of the main outline" Why not? aside is a sectioning element, too, and it does not introduce a sectioning root unlike body, figure, and blockquote.

Comment: @EdHeal "No implementation exists" including screen readers. I've tried one screen reader program and it only paid attention to the order of the header tags.

Comment: @BoltClock Assuming the "intended usage" of `<aside>` for stuff like advertisements, I don't think it makes sense for an advertisement to be a part of the outline.

Comment: So using one screen reader you conclude "no implementation exists". Also how about screen readers etc. that are being developed

Comment: I got the quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document) and the HTML spec.

Comment: Ah, right. There isn't a way to hide content from the outline that I'm aware of (I'm not sure if any of the ARIA roles fits this), and I can definitely see wanting to prevent ads from showing up in the outline.

Comment: @BoltClock The advertisement example is not a particularly egregious one. In general my overarching concern is that because the new tags currently lack semantic information in widespread implementation, that they add no value. If I *were* to use them as they were intended, it would make structuring a document more difficult because it semi-conflicts with the current way of how outlines are generated.

Answer (score 1):

The document outline, and semantics are two separate matters. You are correct in that no user-facing outline implementations exist — the only implementations are in tools created specifically for this purpose, and conformance checkers. This is why the spec recommends continuing to use h1–h6 to mark up headings.

But HTML5 semantics on their own are widely implemented across modern browsers and accessibility tools today. Some HTML5 semantic elements even have ARIA roles built into them for you. See the [ARIA in HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#sec-strong-native-semantics), [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=wai-aria), as well as [this test](http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/landmarks.html) (which caniuse.com itself links to).

Compare the following snippets (with the headings changed to account for missing outlining alg):

```
<h1>Types of dogs</h1>
<section>
 <h2>Doberman</h2>
 <aside>
  <h3>Advertisement</h3>
 </aside>
</section>
```

```
<h1>Types of dogs</h1>
<div class=section>
 <h2>Doberman</h2>
 <div class=ad>
  <h3>Advertisement</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

If you need to support user agents that don't understand HTML5, you can either just shim the elements in, or go with the legacy markup. Either way the two snippets will be semantically meaningless to those user agents.

If you don't need to support legacy browsers, the first snippet is semantically meaningful whereas the second is... not so. Class names don't have any intrinsic semantic value no matter what you name them — they are there solely for the author's convenience. At best, all you have is a series of generic sections and subsections. An h3 in an ad section is no different from an h3 in a content subsection.

Of course, a human reader could still infer meaning from the elements by looking at the class names, but having everything in divs gets messy very, very quickly.

Frankly, I can't think of any reason to use legacy markup in new sites today other than to support legacy browsers. If anything, HTML5 semantic markup ought to be the default. Remember, content is king, and we're dealing with a language that was designed for content on the web. But I'm quickly veering into opinionated territory here.

Note that I haven't made a single mention of CSS here. That's because CSS is completely irrelevant when talking about semantic markup. Semantics are most effective when your document is consumed independently of any CSS.

Comment: If you end up replacing `<div>` with `<section>` etc. it's more readable but not necessarily future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

> Whatever you call them — blocks, boxes, areas, regions — we’ve been dividing our Web pages into visible sections for well over a decade. The problem is, we’ve never had the right tools to do so. While our interfaces look all the world like grids, the underlying structure has been cobbled together from numbered headings and unsemantic helper elements; an unbridled stream of content at odds with its own box-like appearance.

Source:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/01/the-importance-of-sections/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for help on citing external sources.

Comment: Thank you... I really appreciate it.